# How do I over-align a variable in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust

In my code, I have a type that is aligned to 1 byte, and a function that requires a type that is aligned to 8 bytes. The following hypothetical code shows this usage:

```rust
fn use_bar(bar: &mut [u64; 25]) {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo: [u8; 200] = get_foo();

    unsafe {
        // Option 1
        use_bar(mem::transmute::<&mut [u8; 200], &mut [u64; 25]>::(&mut foo));
        // Option 2
        use_bar(&mut *(&mut foo as *mut [u8; 200] as *mut [u64; 25]));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't necessarily work. If you ask clippy about the first option, it will tell you that transmuting references is a bad thing to do. Option 2 may work, however, it will then tell you that the alignment requirements for `[u64; 25]` are more strict (8 byte alignment) than for `[u8; 200]` (1 byte alignment) so this may cause undefined behaviour.

Since I don't control the type returned by `get_foo()`, is there any way I can force `foo` to be 8 byte aligned? (other than wrapping it in a struct that is properly aligned)

Comment: The warning is correct - you're literally in the textbook definition of UB there. Is there a reason you're not just chunking the slice and then parsing to u64 use `read_u64`?

Comment: Both the `get_foo()` and `use_bar()` functions are library-provided (by different libraries) so I can't change those signatures. Chunking the slice and then copying would work, but that requires a copy. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I can think of at least one way to do it without copy, since you don't actually need to destructure the slice and recreate, just take successive slices of it. However, even if there was a copy, I'm sure we can both agree that extra allocations are much easier to justify than UB.

Comment: Maybe, but that is not exactly the question. The question is whether it is possible to avoid UB altogether by ensuring that `foo` is always properly aligned. Also note that these variables are not slices but arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`align_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to) to get an aligned slice.

To get data aligned in the first place, you can use a wrapper with `#[repr(align(x))]`:

```rust
#[repr(align(8))] 
struct Wrapper([u8; 200]);
```